# Semantic error at paths./MyType.get.responses.200.schema.$ref $ref values must be RFC3986-compliant percent-encoded URIs

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata, swagger-2.0

I have an OData api and I enabled swagger for that. When I paste the json information of my OData api in "editor.swagger.io" then it gives me the error :
(Semantic error at paths
  ./BankBranches.get.responses.200.schema.$ref $ref values must be
   RFC3986-compliant percent-encoded URIs)

I have below lines in responses :

responses:
  '200': 
    description: OK 
    schema: 
      $ref: '#/definitions/ODataResponse[List[BankBranch]]'

I know that I can solve the problem by removing all the "[" , "]" but It is too hard and takes too much time in big projects.
I do not know how to change in my OData api to do not have this problem??

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: I do not know how to explain better. Briefly say that I installed swashbuckle.OData and swashbuckle in my api that I made with OData. When I run the application then in browser I put "http://localhost:53000/swagger" in address bar and it gives me its swagger document. And I paste the received address(http://localhost:53000/swagger/docs/v1) in address bar of another tab in my browser and then it gives me some data in json format and I paste whole of that data to website of "editor.swagger.io" and then I encounter upper error in "editor.swagger.io".

Comment: The error is ==>> Semantic error at paths./BankBranches.get.responses.200.schema.$ref
$ref values must be RFC3986-compliant percent-encoded URIs

Comment: As you know there is a part in "editor.swagger.io" that it is "responses:".
I have below codes in this part :

Comment: responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/ODataResponse[List[BankAcc]]'

Comment: There must not be "[" , "]"  in   $ref: '#/definitions/ODataResponse[List[BankAcc]].

Comment: Please give me your email to send my yamel file to you!

Answer (score 1):

if your swaggerResponse looks something like

```
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "OK Result", typeof(IEnumerable<int>))]
```

you could create a wrapper for the response

```
public class MyResponse: IEnumerable<ItemGroup>> {}
```

and update

```
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "OK Result", typeof(MyResponse))]
```